# Passing single user input to detect number and letters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="txtName">Name</label>
  <input type="text" pInputText class="form-control" id="txtName" 
         formControlName="name">
   <div *ngIf="!utenteform.controls['name'].valid && 
               utenteform.controls['name'].dirty" class="alert alert danger">
                 You can't skip this field
   </div>
</div>
```

What i want to achieve is to detect if the user is writing a letter or a number and, if a number is pressed, to give an alert.

I found the "ngKeyDown" event but i can't understand how to use it to pass the every single button pressed to a method that will check what has been typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar case for yours: [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3q5mb6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">
```

---

```
onKeydown(event) {
  if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) {
    alert("input was number");
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent nubmers
  }
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    alert("input was letter");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, please avoid link only answers. Can you add the relevant code to your answer please?

Comment: @user184994, that was my answer there in the link, whatever, updated answer.

Comment: I know, but that link may not last forever. By providing the code in your question, it means the answer remains useful, even if that stackblitz is lost.

Comment: @selemmn thanks! This is what i want but, if i'm not bothering you, how can i delete a number pressed? I see the alert pops up but the number is still inserted inside the textbox. (anyway i'm accepting your answer, thank you again)

Comment: @You're welcome & thanks !, tell me if am not getting you right, you do not want the number to be written from the begin ?

Comment: @selemmn Yes exactly! If the user press a number I want the alert (which you already give me in your code) and I want to delete the input the User pressed (since it is a number and I don't want a number in the name field for example). I can figure out how to avoid other key like "@" or "!" myself.

Comment: @MarcoMoscati if that updated answer did not work for you that's because i forgot to add curly braces after the two `if` s, recheck it please :)

Comment: @selemmn Ahahahah the code worked perfectly i just needed how to set up the onkeydown event